# Jquery script taking very very long time

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below Jquery script taking very very long time.Please provide me the solution so that the performance is increased

for

```
(i = 0; i < fooLength; ++i) {


  if (foo[i] != "") {

  var option = foo[i].split("$");

    if (option.length == 2) {

     if ($("#" + destination).find("option[value='" + option[1] + "']").length == 0)
     {

       $("#" + destination).append($('<option></option>').val(option[1]).html(option[0]));

       $("#" + source).find("option[value='" + option[1] + "']").remove();

     }

    }

   }

  }
```

I am tring to append the value into the listbox.Nearly 5000 records are there so its iterating for 5000 times and takes a long time

Comment: Because you are doing tons of DOM look ups and DOM operations. Learn to store things into variables instead of looking them up, time after time.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: are the records very big?? where do they come from ? can we see an example of how do the records look like? also as far as I can see you would only need some of the records, how many of the 5000 are "valid" more or less? I think if you had the 5000 records on a database, query for the valid records to narrow it down and then append to the listbox you could save a lot of time.

Comment: Better if asked on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to select the elements each and every loop:

```
var $dest = $("#" + destination), $src = $("#" + source);
for (i = 0; i < fooLength; ++i) {
    if (foo[i] != "") {
        var option = foo[i].split("$");
        if (option.length == 2) {
            if ($dest.find("option[value='" + option[1] + "']").length == 0) {
                $dest.append($('').val(option[1]).html(option[0]));
                $src.find("option[value='" + option[1] + "']").remove();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this but there was no much improvement. So by analysis i found the find() is taking lot more time. I replaced this code with below code and there was massive improvement.

```
for (i = 0; i < fooLength; ++i) {
if (foo[i] != "") {
var option = foo[i].split("$");
if (option.length == 2) {

if ($dest.each(function(){("option[value='" + option[1] + "']").length == 0;})){
   $dest.append($('<option></option>').val(option[1]).html(option[0]));
   $src.each(function(){if($(this).val()=="option[value='" + option[1] + "']")$(this).remove();});

                }
            }
        }
    }
```